# How to sort an array based on the length of each digit?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
arr[] = {0010,1,001,01}
```

I need to sort the array in ascending order based on the number of digits it has,
the output should be:

```
arr[] = {1,01,001,0010}
```

I tried to get the number of digits of each element and save it in another array like:

```
digits[] = {4,1,3,2}
```

And when i sort `digits[]`, it should reflect in `arr[]`

Comment: These number have NOT digits You think (BTW are octal)

Comment: 0 = 00 = 000 = 0000.. look at each in printf-%d. (The question might be better suited with *real-data* / integers-without-leading-zeros as an example..)

Comment: `1 = 01` (the second being the *octal* form of `1`) - your compiler may warn you about `0010` and `001` as there is no `00` prefix specified by the C standard (but most compilers will accept the values as `1` anyway).

Comment: What is the `type` that precedes `arr[]` in your declaration of `arr`?

Comment: @davidcrankin It's an integer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use qsort with customized compare function like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* arr[] = {"0000","0","000","00"};


int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
    // or as below if you compare length only
    /*
     return strlen(pa)-strlen(pb);
    */
}

int main() {
    int i;

    int stringLen = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char *);
    qsort(arr, stringLen, sizeof(char *), myCompare);

    for (i=0; i<stringLen; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

the output will be:

```
0: 0    
1: 00   
2: 000  
3: 0000
```

Comment: You buried the lead -- you had to change it to an array of strings, not an array of numbers.

Comment: @yu so it's not possible to sort without using inbuilt functions?

Comment: The build-in functions are simple, you can implement your own version easely